# MonoTouch binding not creating partial classes

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, binding, xamarin.ios

I'm attempting to do what is shown on the MonoTouch [binding page](http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types) and add some methods to a bound class. It says that all I have to do is include these in a partial class defined in a separate file that is included in the generation process with the -s option. The problem is that the generated class is not a partial class and when I run btouch I get the following errors:

> $ /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch -v Node.cs -s:Extensions.cs 
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs -unsafe -target:library Node.cs -nowarn:436 -out:/var/folders/cy/g71b7mr91rn4slbpq5cm39140000gn/T/u983s550.k1k/temp.dll -r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/btouch/btouch.exe Extensions.cs   -r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll
>   Node.cs(7,19): error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type `NodeNameSpace.Node'. Another partial declaration of this type exists
>   Extensions.cs(5,30): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
>   Extensions.cs(5,30): error CS0261: Partial declarations of`NodeNameSpace.Node' must be all classes, all structs or all interfaces
>   Node.cs(7,19): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
>   Extensions.cs(7,29): error CS0106: The modifier `public' is not valid for this item
>   Extensions.cs(10,25): error CS0531:`NodeNameSpace.Node.IsExpanded.get': interface members cannot have a definition
>   Extensions.cs(14,25): error CS0531: `NodeNameSpace.Node.IsExpanded.set': interface members cannot have a definition
>   Compilation failed: 5 error(s), 0 warnings
>   btouch: API binding contains errors.

According to the MonoTouch page on [binding](http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types):

> Each class produced by the generator from the API definition file is a partial class

**Node.cs**

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;

namespace NodeNameSpace
{
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    interface Node
    {
        [Export ("expanded")]
        NSNumber Expanded { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Extensons.cs**

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;

namespace NodeNameSpace 
{
    public partial class Node
    {
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get
            {
                return Expanded.BoolValue;
            }
            set
            {
                Expanded = NSNumber.FromBool(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a long documentation page, but this should do what you want:

```
$ /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch Node.cs -x:Extensions.cs  
$ ls -l Node.dll 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 sebastienpouliot  staff  5120 30 Sep 13:30 Node.dll
```

Your issue was using **-s** which is used when compiling your interface to a partial class (too early for extensions methods) and to compile the bindings to a .dll.

What you wanted is **-x** where the source file would only be used for the second compilation (source to .dll). The **-s** option is most useful for **enums** since you'll need them in *both* your interfaces and in the final assembly (.dll).

To get further help do:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch --help
```

Comment: I don't see -x in the help. I also get an error when I try to use it: error CS2007: Unrecognized command-line option: `-x:Extensions.cs'

Comment: $ /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --version
mtouch 4.2.2.1317158288

Comment: Sorry it's an old change (September 5th) but it looks like it was not backported to the monotouch-4.2 branch. It *will be* available in future version (coming from 'master'). In the mean time you can contact support@xamarin.com to request an updated binary of the tool (just link to this question).

Comment: The answer that I posted works with what is released currently. When the -x option is available in the released version I'll try it out and then update the answer.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to help (upvoted you ;-) You can also build it from source code since the **btouch** tool is open source (check the 'maccore' module in mono's GIT repository at github). See https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/btouch.cs

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that page is out of date. Doing some more searching I found the this [post](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Error-regenerating-a-dll-after-upgrading-to-Monotouch-4-0-tp3436520p3436520.html) in the forums.

The correct command to compile my example above is:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch -v Node.cs --sourceonly genfiles --outdir=gen
```

followed by:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs -out:Node.dll `cat genfiles` Extensions.cs -r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll -target:library
```

Comment: This works with what is released currently. When the -x option is available in the released version I'll try it out and then update the answer.